# Unicode Characters and some fonts cant be seen in installed third-party browsers in Debian 10 Buster

Tags: linux, google-chrome, unicode, opera, debian-buster

I have a laptop running on Debian 10 Buster. However, I am unable to view Unicode characters and some fonts in Chrome browser and Opera browser. Nevertheless, I am able to view Unicode characters in the preinstalled Firefox browser in Debian 10 Buster. Would anyone be able to help in this regard.

EDIT: Please refer this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/hcmicc/unicode_characters_cant_be_seen_in_installed/) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/hcmicc/unicode_characters_cant_be_seen_in_installed/) for more info.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Comment: Check the font used in chrome and opera contains unicode characters ...

Comment: Hi, I changed it to the default font that Firefox uses. It did not fix the problem. Just wanted to let you know it is the coloured Unicode characters and some fonts that are not displaying. Please refer this reddit thread please for more info. https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/hcmicc/unicode_characters_cant_be_seen_in_installed/   Thanks & Best Regards Michael